# org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray in Android Studio

Tags: android

I want to retrieve a row in my PHP MySQL and put it in my spinner. I have this of error:

```
06-13 04:56:53.656 10276-10342/com.example.eugene.spinnersql W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value {"result":[{"DriverID":"28","VehicleID":"122","BodyType":"Sedan","Make":"Toyota","Series":"Vios"},{"DriverID":"28","VehicleID":"119","BodyType":"Sedan","Make":"Honda","Series":"Civic"}]} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
06-13 04:56:53.657 10276-10342/com.example.eugene.spinnersql W/System.err:     at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
06-13 04:56:53.657 10276-10342/com.example.eugene.spinnersql W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:96)
06-13 04:56:53.657 10276-10342/com.example.eugene.spinnersql W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:108)
06-13 04:56:53.657 10276-10342/com.example.eugene.spinnersql W/System.err:     at com.example.eugene.spinnersql.DataParser.parseData(DataParser.java:66)
06-13 04:56:53.657 10276-10342/com.example.eugene.spinnersql W/System.err:     at com.example.eugene.spinnersql.DataParser.doInBackground(DataParser.java:61)
06-13 04:56:53.657 10276-10342/com.example.eugene.spinnersql W/System.err:     at com.example.eugene.spinnersql.DataParser.doInBackground(DataParser.java:19)
06-13 04:56:53.657 10276-10342/com.example.eugene.spinnersql W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
06-13 04:56:53.657 10276-10342/com.example.eugene.spinnersql W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
06-13 04:56:53.657 10276-10342/com.example.eugene.spinnersql W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
06-13 04:56:53.657 10276-10342/com.example.eugene.spinnersql W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
06-13 04:56:53.657 10276-10342/com.example.eugene.spinnersql W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
06-13 04:56:53.657 10276-10342/com.example.eugene.spinnersql W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
06-13 04:56:53.725 10276-10311/com.example.eugene.spinnersql W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-13 04:56:53.725 10276-10311/com.example.eugene.spinnersql W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xdfefe220, error=EGL_SUCCESS
```

Here is my Data Parser.

```
 private int parseData(){
    try {
        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(jsonData);
        JSONObject jo = null;

        vehicles.clear();
        Vehicle s = null;

        for(int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++){
            jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);

            int vehicleid = jo.getInt("VehicleID");
            String make = jo.getString("Make");
            String series = jo.getString("Series");

            s = new Vehicle();
            s.setVehicleID(vehicleid);
            s.setMake(make);
            s.setSeries(series);

            vehicles.add(vehicleid + " " + make + " " + series);
        }

        return 1;

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is my Data Downloader:

```
private String downloadData(){
    HttpURLConnection con = Connector.connect(urlAddress);
    if(con==null){
        return null;
    }

    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

        String line=null;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        if(bufferedReader != null){

            while((line=bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                response.append(line+"\n");
            }

            bufferedReader.close();

        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return response.toString();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(inputStream != null){
            try{
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

This is my Connector:

```
public static HttpURLConnection connect(String urlAddress){
    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlAddress);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setConnectTimeout(20000);
        con.setReadTimeout(20000);
        con.setDoInput(true);

        return con;
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Here is my Data Getter and Setter:

```
public class Vehicle {

int VehicleID;
String Make, Series;


public int getVehicleID() {
    return VehicleID;
}

public void setVehicleID(int vehicleID) {
    VehicleID = vehicleID;
}

public String getMake() {
    return Make;
}

public void setMake(String make) {
    Make = make;
}

public String getSeries() {
    return Series;
}

public void setSeries(String series) {
    Series = series;
}

}
```

Comment: learn some JSON basics ... `{"result":[...]}` is not a JSONArray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your json data is of type JSONObject. The JSONArray you want is nested in it under key `"result"`. You can retrieve it like this

```
JSONArray ja = new JSONObject(jsonData).getJSONArray("result"));
```

Comment: Thanks men! You're my savior! :D

Answer (score 0):

Put below code in parse json Object

```
String result;
result = jsonData.getString("result");
JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(result);
```

Just replace this code with your ja code and run this .

Hope this will help you ! cheers !

Answer (score 0):

Replace your parseData() method with below code and you won't get any error in parsing:

```
private int parseData(){
        try {
            JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(new JSONObject(jsonData));
            JSONObject jo = null;

            vehicles.clear();
            Vehicle s = null;

            for(int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++){
                jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);

                int vehicleid = Integer.parseInt(jo.getString("VehicleID"));
                String make = jo.getString("Make");
                String series = jo.getString("Series");

                s = new Vehicle();
                s.setVehicleID(vehicleid);
                s.setMake(make);
                s.setSeries(series);

                vehicles.add(vehicleid + " " + make + " " + series);
            }

            return 1;

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

`JSONObject` data coming from server not `JSONArray` data

```
ArrayList<Vehicle>  arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
     private int parseData(){
        try {

            JSONObject object= new JSONObject(jsonData);
            JSONArray ja = object.getJSONArray("result");
            vehicles.clear();
            for(int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++){
                JSONObject jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);
                Vehicle Ve = new Vehicle();

                Ve.setVehicleID(jo.getInt("VehicleID"));
                Ve.setMake(jo.getString("Make"));
                Ve.setSeries(jo.getString("Series"));

                vehicles.add(Ve);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

         Toast.makeText(this,"Size of List="+arrayList.size(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: Naming a variable `object` is a really odd choice

Comment: @TimCastelijns thanx will improved